# Conveying the idea of "(it) speaks for itself" (i.e. sth is clear and needs no further explanation)

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, anglicismes

What are some colloquial ways to express the idea of "(it) speaks for itself" meaning that something is clear and needs no further explanation?

I have seen examples with "(Quelque chose/Cela) parle d'elle-même/lui-même" but it sounds "anglaisé". I have seen also éloquent(e). But it sounds to me very formal.

For instance

> Canada's record on justice issues speaks for itself.
>
> Le bilan du Canada en matière de justice parle de lui-même.
>
> Le bilan du Canada en matière de justice est suffisamment éloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Parle de lui-même

N'est pas du tout un anglicisme. C'est une tournure tout à fait correcte en français.

---

It's not "anglaisé", it is a perfectly valid expression in French.

Comment: Merci. J'ai connu de parle de lui-même concernant des personnes. Je me suis demandé si l'on peut utiliser pour des choses. It's ok now :-)!

Comment: Pour une personne j'aurai plutôt entendu "parle pour lui-même" (Dans le sens "exprime une opinion personnelle"), ce n'ai pas la même chose. "Parle de lui-même" translate more to "self-explaining".

Comment: J'aurais ajouté l'expression "Ça va de soi" qui me parait tout aussi courante.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said by others, "parler de soi-meme" is the corresponding French structure. A couple of examples:

- " *Ce film n'a pas besoin de résumé, l'affiche parle **d'elle-même*** " : this movie does not need a summary, the poster speaks for itself.
- " *Ces esclaves n'ont pas besoin de pleurer, leurs visages parlent **d'eux-mêmes*** " : These slaves do not need to cry, their faces speak for themselves.
- " *Ce peintre n'a pas besoin d'expliquer, son tableau parle **de lui-même*** " : This painter does not need to explain, his painting speaks for itself.